# Not able to find correct indexOf value by clicking an array element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code for html and js are as:

### html

```
<img ng-repeat = "x in images" ng-src = "{{x.url}}" ng-click = "mag(x)">
```

### js

```
$scope.images = [img1, img2, img3, img4] 
var l;
$scope.mag = function(x){
  l = $scope.images.indexOf(x);
  console.log("value of l "+l);
}
```

`img1, img2...` are dummy objects in which their ulrs exist.

As I click over `first image`, in `console.log()` it is showing `value of l is 0` which is `correct` but on clicking `2nd` image, value of `l is again 0 instead of 1`, on clicking  `3rd` image value of `l is 1 instead of 2` and on clicking  `4th` image value of `l is 2 instead of 3`.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Just debug a bit more: print not only the value of `l`, but also the array and `x`, so that you can manually check again.

Comment: Please don't use `l` as a variable name. It's too easy to confuse with `1`, especially in this context. Your question is difficult to follow.

Comment: x of images....

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is just the index of the element, you can use the `$index`.

Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Example:

`<img ng-repeat = "x in images" ng-src = "{{x.url}}" ng-click = "mag($index)">`

```
$scope.mag = function(index){
  console.log("value of index is: "+index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</h1>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]
            var l;
            $scope.mag = function(x){
            l = $scope.images.indexOf(x);
            console.log("value of l "+l);
          };
    });
    </script>

</body>
```